# Removing wall under truss

Tags: walls, truss

I am wanting to turn this wall into a pony wall to open up my kitchen. It is directly under a truss. It contained a pocket door and there is no floor joist running under it or no other load bearing item in the basement under it. The top plate of the wall intersects the top plate of the exterior wall and is directly under the truss. The yellow circle is the truss and the red is the top plate of the interior wall interlcoking the exterior wall top plate.

What, if anything, can be done to safely remove the top plate of the wall? Can the 2x4 be cut flushed?

[image: truss][image: wall to remove]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's going to be hard for us to answer; you may need to get a structural engineer in. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

The wall is not structural and the top plate tie-in is not structural if, 1) the trusses are tied to the remaining wall, 2) the top plate is spliced properly.

1) Any lateral bracing that the wall could provide, can be taken by attaching the existing roof trusses to the top plate. I like using Simpson H-1 clips to tie the truss to the top plate. I like the H-1 because it provides lateral resistance and uplift resistance. 
See: https://www.strongtie.com/resources/product-installers-guide/h1-installation

2) The existing top plates need to be properly lapped (spliced), which now needs something like Simpson LSTI strap. I like the LSTI strap because it’s made for application on a single plate. See: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-LSTI-3-3-4-in-x-49-in-18-Gauge-Strap-Tie-LSTI49/205326016

The bottom plate extends past the wall, so provide a block at the top plate where the wall is removed and center the strap at the intersection of where the wall was located.